# find ALL methods of getting current date/time in VB.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, date, time

I have a 500K+ lines vb.net app, written by 10+ different devs over the past 5 years. Many times it gets the system time and/or date and relies on it.

Now I have to re-run real cases thru the program for regression testing purposes, and it screws up cases where the date/time matter. My fix is easy, just replace all the areas in the program that get current date/time with a sub that gets the current date/time, UNLESS I'm testing, in which case it will return the date/time of the original run.

I have tried searching the sourcecode for the obvious 'current date/time' functions:

```
Now
DateAndTime.TimeOfDay
Date.ToDay
```

However, if I miss one, **I LOSE.**

Can anybody please list more ways to get the current time, that might be hidden in the source code, that I can search for? Note: It's pretty clear none of the 3rd party libs in this system are returning date, well, one is, but I've caught it. so just from .net or vb. Thanks.

Comment: That's all that I can think of short of P/Invoking. http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.setsystemtime

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the technique described by @Hans Passant.  For a complete list of VB.NET functions related to system clock, look [here](http://www.maconstateit.net/Tutorials/VBNET/VBNET01/vbnet01-07.aspx).

```
DateString
Now
TimeOfDay
Timer
TimeString
Today
DateAdd
DateDiff
DatePart
DateSerial
DateValue
Day
IsDate
Month
MonthName
Weekday
Hour
Minute
Second
TimeSerial
TimeValue
```

Comment: thanks ed, I was just looking for a quick list like this. Your google-fu is strong, mine is weak...

Comment: Those are the VB.NET specific functions, but you'll probably want to include the .NET Framework functions as well.  Look at the `DateTime` and `DateTimeOffset` structures for static methods.

Answer (score 3):

Find one, right-click, Find All References.

Reflector can help too.  Right-click the property getter, Analyze, Used by.

Answer (score 2):

The following also get the current date and time:

```
DateTime.Now
DateTime.UtcNow
DateTime.Today
DateTimeOffset.Now
DateTimeOffset.UtcNow
```

Is that all of them?  Somehow I doubt it.